# Browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) routes to incorrect server for domain

Tags: macos, dns

I purchased a new domain for my website at Hover.com. I pointed the name servers to my host provider. Everything works smoothly when I access the site on my iPhone, iPad, on my roommate's laptop, or any other machine.

But on my MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion, when I try to load my website at the new domain, I'm directed to a Hover.com landing page. The old domain (which I still have pointed to the same place) works fine, but the new one does not, and it's only on my machine that I have this problem. Changing browsers does not help. I tried clearing the DNS cache like so

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

but that does not fix the problem. Any ideas? My new domain name is andrewphilipclark.com.

Comment: Cached DNS lookups on the MacBook?

Comment: Doesn't the command I posted flush the DNS cache? I don't know much about this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resolved itself... somehow. I guess somewhere between my MacBook and my server there was a DNS cache that needed to be cleared. Kinda wished I knew what the issue was so I could learn from it, but oh well.